# If else selector ignored?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I want to make two different headers for my WordPress project, so the frontpage will display differently than the rest of the pages. I would do it with an if/else statement, but it seems that the last part of the string is being ignored.

What could trigger this?

The code looks like this and links to two id's in a separate css file. The first statement "top_frontpage" goes through all the pages instead of grapping "top_sub" when on the sub pages.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page ) { echo '<div id="top_frontpage">'; } else { echo '<div id="top_sub">'; }; ?>
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: by the way, what is `is_front_page` - it doesn't look like a variable (missing $) or a function (missing parenthesis)?

Comment: You should get an "undefined constant" notice here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) is a function.

You need to use

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() )
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to what @Pekka said - you probably want that `is_front_page` to either be `$is_front_page` or `is_front_page()` *because* PHP turns unquoted alphanumeric character sequences (such as `is_front_page`)  into literal strings unless they are defined as constants thus your statement is equivalent to

```
if ('is_front_page') { //this is never going to be false
    //blah
}else{
    //never executed
}
```

Comment: Barewords! Nooo! \*runs away\*

Comment: mm, it is an ugly 'feature' i agree

Comment: It really didn't execute anything <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { echo '<div id="top_frontpage">'; }else{ echo '<div id="top_sub">'; }; ?> even though i named is_front_page "$is_front_page"

Comment: oooh, another 'feature' of PHP - undefined variables are 'falsy' - you'd unconditionally get the else branch if you use `$is_front_page` when, as @Pekka said, `is_front_page` is a _function_ (i.e. you want `is_front_page()`